# What is wrong with this association ? Related data are not being fetched

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.x

```
 function export(){
        ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
        $this->loadModel('Profile');
        $this->loadModel('ExamPayment');
        //$this->loadModel('ExamApplication');
        //$clemrep = $this->ExamApplication->find('all');
        $ufacid = Authcomponent::user('faculty_id');
        $options = array( 'conditions' => array('ExamPayment.status' => "Successful",'ExamPayment.faculty_id'=> $ufacid) );

        $this->ExamPayment->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $this->ExamPayment->contain( 
            array('User'=>array('Profile'),'Exam','Faculty','ExamApplication')
        );
        $examApps = $this->ExamPayment->find('all', $options, array('contain'=>
            'ExamApplication'
        ));
        $examApplications = array();
        foreach ($examApps as $key => $examApplication) {

            $fname = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['fname'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['fname'] ):null;
            $lname = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['lname'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['lname'] ):null;
            $phone = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['phone'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['phone'] ):null;
            $gender = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['gender'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['gender'] ):null;
            $nationality = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['nationality'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['nationality'] ):null;

            //$adddress = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['adddress'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['adddress'] ):null;
            //$dob = isset($examApplication['User']['Profile']['dob'])? trim($examApplication['User']['Profile']['dob'] ):null;

            $examApplications[] = array(
                'ExamApplication' => array(
                    'full_name' => $fname . ' ' . $lname,
                    'email' => $examApplication['User']['email'],
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    //'adddress' => $adddress,
                    //'date_of_birth' => $dob,
                    'gender' => $examApplication['User']['Profile']['gender'],
                    'nationality' => $examApplication['User']['Profile']['nationality'],
                    // 'state' => $examApplication['User']['Profile']['state'],
                    //'ref_number' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['ref_number'],
                    //'role' => $examApplication['User']['role'],
                    'exam' => $examApplication['Exam']['exam'],
                    //'init' => $examApplication['Exam']['init'],
                    'code' => $examApplication['Faculty']['code'],
                    'med_school' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['med_school'],
                    'med_school_address' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['med_school_address'],
                    'med_school_year' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['med_school_year'],
                    'med_board_year' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['med_board_year'],
                    'discharge_year' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['discharge_year'],
                    'discharge_type' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['discharge_type'],
                    'exam_date' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['exam_date'],
                    'exam_center' => $examApplication['ExamApplication']['exam_center'],
                    //'exam_fee' => $examApplication['ExamPayment']['exam_fee'],
                    'status' => $examApplication['ExamPayment']['status'],
                )   
            );
        }
        //pr($clemrep);
        pr($examApplications);
        exit();

        $this->set(compact('examApplications'));

        $this->layout = null;
        $this->autoLayout = false;
        Configure::write('debug','0');
    }[attached is the output i get][1]
```

Below is the ouput of the array, my question is, why are some value blank?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ExamApplication] => Array
                (
                    [full_name] => FRANK CHIDI NWANKPA
                    [email] => franknwankpa@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 07030940000
                    [gender] => Male
                    [nationality] => NG
                    [exam] => Primary
                    [code] => 205
                    [med_school] => 
                    [med_school_address] => 
                    [med_school_year] => 
                    [med_board_year] => 
                    [discharge_year] => 
                    [discharge_type] => 
                    [exam_date] => 
                    [exam_center] => 
                    [status] => Successful
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ExamApplication] => Array
                (
                    [full_name] => BANKOLE ARAFAT ABOSEDE
                    [email] => bankolearafat@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 08062683798
                    [gender] => Female
                    [nationality] => NG
                    [exam] => Primary
                    [code] => 205
                    [med_school] => 
                    [med_school_address] => 
                    [med_school_year] => 
                    [med_board_year] => 
                    [discharge_year] => 
                    [discharge_type] => 
                    [exam_date] => 
                    [exam_center] => 
                    [status] => Successful
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ExamApplication] => Array
                (
                    [full_name] => Uvieroghene Ogbebor
                    [email] => uvieo@yahoo.com
                    [phone] => 08038975401
                    [gender] => Male
                    [nationality] => NG
                    [exam] => Primary
                    [code] => 205
                    [med_school] => 
                    [med_school_address] => 
                    [med_school_year] => 
                    [med_board_year] => 
                    [discharge_year] => 
                    [discharge_type] => 
                    [exam_date] => 
                    [exam_center] => 
                    [status] => Successful
                )

        )
```

why are some values blank, i found out that the content of the "ExamApplication" model is not being displayed , however, the model has already been loaded.

What could be happening?

Please help me

Comment: Please tag your questions only with the version that you are actually using - thanks!

Comment: @ ndm, it is cake 2.x

Comment: please post the result of `debug($examApps )`

Comment: @arilia 
            [ExamApplication] array is still empty, what could be wrong?

Comment: means probably that `$options` are not matched. Try to debug the generated query (enable debug mode or debugKit) and test it in your DB

Comment: @ arilia, you mean in my model? which model?

Comment: @arilia, nothing is wrong with the $options

Comment: I asked you to debug the query. Then copy/paste the generated query in your DB (i.e. phpmyadmin) and try if it gives the desidered records.